# set index to table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a table that has 30 rows. 
i wrote the below code to set number index to each row.from 1-to 30
this code works good.
but when the variable that called : cyrrentpage has 2 as  content . the row number added 1 before index . instead of start with 31.
what should i do ?
here is my snippet:

```js
var cyrrentpage =2
if(cyrrentpage == 1)
{
  $(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text( $(this).closest("tr").index()+1)
});
}
else
{
$(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {
          
  if(index == 50)
  {
    $(this).text("cyrrentpage 0");        
  }
          else{
    $(this).text( (cyrrentpage-1).toString()+($(this).closest("tr").index()+1).toString())
        }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `(cyrrentpage-1).toString()+($(this).closest("tr").index()+1).toString()` appends strings instead of adding numbers.

Comment: You have to add string not append to the string

Comment: @NisargShah where shoud i append this?

Comment: You have to use the unary plus operator to convert them to numbers first.

`+num1 + +num2;`

Comment: `(cyrrentpage-1) + ($(this).closest("tr").index()+1)` should work

Comment: @YogeshMistry when i use of this code it is not working because currentpage value is 1 i want to start from 1 to 30 . when current page value is 2 i want to start from 31 to 60. and etc

Comment: @inaz try this `($(this).closest("tr").index()+1) + 30*(cyrrentpage-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$(this).text( (cyrrentpage-1).toString()+($(this).closest("tr").index()+1).toString())
```

should be

```
$(this).text(30*(cyrrentpage-1).toString()+ +($(this).closest("tr").index()+1).toString())
```

Notice that unary `+` converts it to a number.

Comment: it's not work .when the current page value is 2 . i want to start with 31.

Comment: yes . it worked thank you so much for your prompt response

Answer (score 1):

```
var cyrrentpage =2;
var amount = 30;
$(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text( ($(this).closest("tr").index()+((cyrrentpage-1)*amount))+1)
});
```

```js
var cyrrentpage =2;
var amount = 30;
$(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text( ($(this).closest("tr").index()+((cyrrentpage-1)*amount))+1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="row_number">1</td><td> hello</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appneding strings, instead of adding numbers.

```
(cyrrentpage-1).toString()+($(this).closest("tr").index()+1)‌​.toString()
```

As per your comments, if you want to start the second page with 31, the following expression will work for you:

```
$(this).text(((cyrrentpage - 1) * 30) + ($(this).closest("tr").index() + 1));
```

```js
var cyrrentpage = 2
if (cyrrentpage == 1) {
  $(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text($(this).closest("tr").index() + 1)
  });
} else {
  $(".row_number").each(function(index, element) {

    if (index == 50) {
      $(this).text("cyrrentpage 0");
    } else {
      $(this).text(((cyrrentpage - 1) * 30) + ($(this).closest("tr").index() + 1));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row_number">1</td>
    <td> hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`$(this).text( (cyrrentpage-1).toString()+($(this).closest("tr").index()+1).toString())`

to

`$(this).text(($(this).closest("tr").index()+1) + 30*(cyrrentpage-1));`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do the same thing in CSS. I take your code and make this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/AGYnt/139/

```
body
{
    counter-reset: Serial;           /* Set the Serial counter to 0 */
}

table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
}

tr td:first-child:before
{
  counter-increment: Serial;      /* Increment the Serial counter */
  content:counter(Serial); /* Display the counter */
}
```

Comment: i have to use jquery. because when currentpage value is 1 i want to start from 1 to 30 . when current page value is 2 i want to start from 31 to 60. and etc.

Comment: You can also start from 2, for example check http://jsfiddle.net/AGYnt/140/ I start counter from 30 in this example